# c# check if list of strings contains certain strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings and an array of forbidden string. I'm looking for a linq expression that selects the strings which are not contained in the forbidden strings array.

Comment: Show some effort, please. For example, you could have visited any LINQ tutorial and read about the extensions methods and see some examples. You would learn more from that than just by asking the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> except = listOfStrings.Except(forbiddenStrings)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
stringlist.Where(x=>!stringarray.Contains(x));
```